# Flutter ObjectBox Mapping and create model

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox

Hello guys I have data models like:

```
class Product {
  int id;
  String name;
  List<ImageList> images;
}

class ImageList {
  String name;
  String src;
}
```

I need to store this data to objectbox

```
@Entity()
class ProductDB {
  ProductDB({
    @Id()
    int id,
    String name,
    images = ToMany<ImageListDB>(),
  )}

}

@Entity()
class ImageListDB {
  ImageListDB({
    this.name
    this.src,
  })

  String name;
  String src;
}
```

how to map(i can't create a constructor in ProductDB with images ) images or store data with the first model to local data db. Sorry for the poor English.

store data from API to local DB with objectbox

Comment: do you need from JsonSerializable?? 
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/main/generator/integration-tests/part-partof/lib/json.dart

Comment: It is explained at https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#to-many-relations how to use ToMany. Let me know why this doesn't work.